# docker exec does not open bash

Tags: docker

```
[root@localhost byo-atomic]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
6c2b1159671e        root/atomicrepo:latest   "/run-apache.sh"    21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   atomicrepo          
[root@localhost byo-atomic]# docker exec -it atomicrepo bash
[root@localhost byo-atomic]# docker logs atomicrepo
Passing arguments to httpd using apachectl is no longer supported.
You can only start/stop/restart httpd using this script.
If you want to pass extra arguments to httpd, edit the
/etc/sysconfig/httpd config file.
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.22. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Comment: can you show your full `docker run` command? Is it detached or not?

Comment: could you try `docker exec -it  6c2b1159671e bash ` # i.e. use your current containerid

Comment: also try `docker exec -it atomicrepo /bin/bash`

Comment: it seems he did it "root@localhost byo-atomic]# docker exec -it atomicrepo bash"